# VS2013 IntelliSense overlapping ReSharper's one

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, intellisense, windows-8.1, resharper-8.0

After installing ReSharper I've noticed a problem with the IntelliSense;

> [image: intellisense overlap]

In the image it is clearly visible that the IntelliSense of Visual Studio is displayed over the one of ReSharper (which by the way has the focus, so using the arrow keys will move the highlight section of the completion list below).
I've tried to do several things without any result (always with VS restart):

- Switch from ReSharper IntelliSense to VS (back and forth)
- Limit ReSharper IntelliSense to some selected languages (i.e. C#)
- Completely disable VS IntelliSense ('Tools | Options | Text Editor | All languages' and 'Tools | Options | Text Editor | C# | IntelliSense')
- Resize ReSharper's completion list
- Re-applying the keyboard shortcuts (Visual Studio)
- Reset VS and repairing the ReSharper installation
- Re-install ReSharper
- Clear all temp folders

None of them helped me fix this issue which results in a particular annoying problem while trying to write anything.

> JetBrains ReSharper 8.2 C# Edition
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 Version 12.0.30110.00 Update 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a conflict with the "plain text completion" feature of the Viasfora extension. It's been fixed in source by detecting when ReSharper is installed: https://github.com/tomasr/viasfora/issues/51 Should be fixed in a new release soon, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! For now I've just disabled the "Enable Plain-Text Completion" from Tools -> Options -> Viasfora.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem without the Viasfora extension:

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> XML -> General
And Disable "Auto list members" and "Parameter information".

seems that resharper disables this features in xaml, but not in xml.
Worked for me with vs2015. Hope this helps.