# XML namespaces suggestions are overlapping with ReSharper xaml suggestions

Tags: xml, xaml, resharper, visual-studio-2015, overlap

When writing xaml in *Visual Studio 2015 Community* with *ReSharper* IntelliSense suggestions are overlapping with the default xml namespaces from Visual Studio.

[image: Overlapping suggestions]

This isn't a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494422/vs2013-intellisense-overlapping-resharpers-one) post since it [was fixed](https://github.com/tomasr/viasfora/issues/51) supposedly a while ago. How can I disable the Visual Studio xml namespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Visual Studio - Options - Text editor - XML - General
- Uncheck "Auto list members"